# MaterialDatePicker is slow

Tags: android, datepicker, material-design, lag

I'm using MaterialDatePicker, but it's slow.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

    MaterialDatePicker.Builder<Long> datePickerBuilder;
    MaterialDatePicker<Long> datePicker;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        datePickerBuilder = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker();
        datePicker = datePickerBuilder.build();

        Button btn = findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                datePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), null);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When the button is pressed for the first time it takes 3 seconds for the Date picker to show. On subsequent button clicks, it open in 1 second. After the selecting a date in date picker gives lag, it's not smooth as you would expect it to be.

Is there any solution to this?

**EDIT:** It seems there are more bugs. There is a lag when changing months by horizontal scrolling and a lot of times, it will slide 2-3 times and end up choosing the wrong month. I don't think MaterialDatePicker is usable, the UX is too bad.

Comment: do you possibly have any background tasks or processes that could be holding up the click of the date picker?

Comment: If you mean in the app, then no. I actually created a new project to see what was causing this lag. That's all this projecr has - one activity only.

Comment: @TayyabMazhar Are you using an actual device or emulator? If  its an actual device, what are the specs? If  you are using an emulator I'd suggest trying a real device.

Comment: try to run your app on multiple devices and see

Comment: @DavidKroukamp It's a physical device Motorolla Moto E5 Android Oreo.

Comment: @Zain I did on my Samsung, it's faster but picking the date inside date picker is still lagy.

Comment: @TayyabMazhar I have S20+ been using the material datepicker myself for another project cant say I see any lag at all, except after I pick the year, it rolls to the current month and day and that is a bit slow but I think its the animation time as opposed to anything else. But seems we arent the only https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/920 https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/707 It does seem like you can "theme"/adjust the motion but there isnt much on it https://material.io/components/pickers#theming

Comment: a non-programming hint, sometimes mobile phones can be slow as there is no enough space on the phone for caching all the running apps, that can produce lagging

Answer (score 1):

I beg your pardon as this should be a comment, but alas I cannot write one, and maybe it can help somebody.

As is happening to @TayyabMazhar, I have also observed that Material Date Picker takes a few seconds to show, and changing months by horizontal scrolling produces visual artifacts.

I observe this both in an app I am developing, as well as in Googles Material demo app (only slightly less so - I can confirm the picker is still slow however: looking at the logcat both apps show quite a few frames being skipped when the picker is launched, ca 45). Funnily enough, while I can see this on my phone (powerful SoC, 6Gb RAM, very few apps installed), I cannot see it when I run, for example, a much less powerful emulated device.

Further, I have tried using different material versions, 1.3.0-alpha02, 1.2.0, 1.1.0... but got the same results.

Comment: I've switch to DatePicker it's smooth.

Comment: I've switched to DatePickerDialog as well and I'm not experiencing any lag anymore.