# How to Reduce Speed of Date_Picker Spinner in Android Material?

Tags: android, android-studio, uiaccessibility, accessibility

Is there an Accessibility setting within the Android OS or if as a developer, how can one reduce the speed of the date_picker spinner. There were up and down arrows in the older UI that allowed the user to change the year by one increment. The new Material UI is an accessibility issue as a simple swipe changes it by many increments. I'm open to suggestions or a solution.

Thanks

Comment: Good question. I can't find the answer, but you might want to add more detail to your question.  Maybe even a picture or two would help like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26854762/android-material-design-inline-datepicker-issue Maybe you can post your question here as well https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/980  It seems like most people are unhappy that it is slow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62704481/materialdatepicker-is-slow

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'll look into this.